# Salesforce through HTTP query retrieves only Limited number of records through the JSON response

Tags: salesforce, hana, salesforce-lightning

I am a Java developer and building a SAP HANA adapter via Java. I need to retrieve records from a Salesforce application to populate HANA tables. So I connect to a Salesforce application through HTTP GET with a Authorization Header and the query goes like `https://<salesforceInstance>/services/data/v42.0/query/?q=<GET query>`. It seems to work fine but my JSON response has only 500 records. However the Salesforce object has over 35000 records. Is there a way that I can retrieve all the records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the response there should be a special link to fetch next chunk of data. It's bit like cursor in a normal database. See "nextrecordsurl" in https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_query.htm

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there a way that I can fetch all records as a single JSON response rather than mini chunks.

Comment: Your application will consume less memory if you work in chunks; pagination is in there to protect the client. But if you really want - look into the Bulk API, https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_bulk_query_intro.htm. It'll work asynchronous, you'd submit a job (your query) and poll the server, "is it done yet"?